# EF Core command denied when command execute,but ado.net was worked

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework

I'm trying to use EF core in my new project,Everything worked on my pc,but some thing error when connect to company db.
Whatever I do,there is a error like 'INSERT/SELECT command denied to user' occured,but the same operation when l do by ADO.NET,it works well.

Have you ever meet this issue,please leave a message for me.
And what should l do to solve this issue?

I have trid that the password was right and connection as

```
"server=xxx;port=3306;database=xxx;user=xxx;password=xxx;sslmode=none;charset=utf8"
EF core error [SELECT Command was denied to use for table]
C#
_dbContext.table.ToList();
```

ADO.Net works well by the same connection and same operation

```
using (var conn = new MySqlConnection(_conn))
{
    using (var cmd = new MySqlCommand(s, conn))
    {
         conn.Open();
         cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
     }
}
```

Comment: this might help: https://billlin.azurewebsites.net/2018/08/22/mysql-with-entity-framework-core-in-asp-net-core/

Comment: Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.Mysql I have also tried ,and it doesn't work.The error seem that happened in the dll [mysql.data] when try to execute command

Comment: make sure the user in the conn string has enough permissions in the db - good luck!

Comment: thank u,I will try again